# Session username only works after using the button

Tags: php, session

I have a code and want to edit it. Now I try to change stuff, but I dont get why it worked before and now it doesn't anymore. First I had this:

```
    <?php
session_start();
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "usbw", "accounts");
$mysqli2 = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "usbw", "forum");
$alles_goed=false;

if (isset($_POST['title'])) {
    $alles_goed=true;
    $description=$_POST['description'];
    $title=$_POST['title'];
    $username=$_SESSION['username'];
    $usernamecheck = $mysqli->query("SELECT * from account_information where username ='". $username ."'");
//etc
```

This was my edit:

```
    <?php
session_start();
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "usbw", "accounts");
$mysqli2 = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "usbw", "forum");
$alles_goed=false;
$username=$_SESSION['username'];
$usernamecheck = $mysqli->query("SELECT * from account_information where username ='". $username ."'");


if (isset($_POST['title'])) {
    $alles_goed=true;
    $description=$_POST['description'];
    $title=$_POST['title'];
    //etc
```

This should work fine right? Still for some reason I get this error:

```
Undefined index: username
```

at:

```
$username=$_SESSION['username'];
```

What am I doing wrong and why isn't the second one possible?

**EDIT:**

I want to not show my form when the SESSION doesn't exists. So I got that but I want the errors gone.

Comment: where did you assign value to $_SESSION['username'] ...?

Comment: @Sudhir At a different PHP page. The $_SESSION['username'] does exist, trust me. It works fine on other pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){
    $username = $_SESSION['username'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

can you please check value is assigned in $_SESSION['username'] or not?

Comment: Okay there isn't a value in because I want to be able to not show the page when the session is empty

Answer (score 0):

the reason is you didn't assign value to $_SESSION['username'], I think on you can print_r($_SESSION) after session_start(); to see the SESSION variable on both page.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that 
when isset($_POST['title']) is false
isset($_SESSION['username']) is also false